# Dutch citizens and NL citizens? tag issue?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Currently we have [nl-citizens](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nl-citizens) and [dutch-citizens](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dutch-citizens).  I assume these should be merged/made synonyms, no?

Comment: btw we have only [tag:nl-citizen] (singular)

Comment: According to this [http://meta.expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/8/what-version-of-country-names-should-we-use] the most upvoted alternative would be [dutch-citizens]

Comment: We don't really have nl-citizen, it's a remnant from my (botched attempt at?) renaming the tag (because of the singular and the country code, which seems to go against the emerging consensus and other tags).

Comment: @GaëlLaurans but the tag will not be autodeleted since it has a tag-wiki

Comment: @Dirty-flow That's what's botched about it ;-) Now, if someone would let me know how to do it properly…